# Exactness of integer division in JS

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision, division

If `a` and `b` are positive integers less than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` and `a` is divisible by `b`, is it guaranteed that `console.log(a / b)` will output an integer (and not, say, a number which ends in `.9999999999`)? Also, would `a % b === 0` always hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least based on the ECMAScript standard, the rules for [applying / operator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-applying-the-div-operator) mention that **the language does not perform integer division** and in the typical case *the quotient is computed and rounded to the nearest representable value using IEEE 754-2008 round to nearest, ties to even mode*.

Hence, if the numerator (within the safe bounds) is evenly divisible by a non-zero denominator, the result is necessarily a mathematical integer since [IEE 754-2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008_revision) can represent that as one.

It is the same for `%` which will yield 0 in such situation.

Comment: Yes, the integer quotient of two integers is always representable, so it must be produced. Similarly, the `%` operator must produce zero. The rounding mode is irrelevant. The IEEE 754 formats do not represent “both integer and floating-point values.” They represent floating-point values, some of which are, mathematically, integers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for making my understanding of it clearer as well!